# Question: Why $(0,\infty) \subset \rho(\Delta_D) $ yields $\sigma(\Delta_D) \subset \mathbb R$?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, semigroup-of-operators

[image]

[image]

As I was studying the proof of the following theorem , I got stuck to the following implication:

> $(0,\infty) \subset \rho(\Delta_D)  \Rightarrow\sigma(\Delta_D)
>  \subset \mathbb R (*)$

With the usual definition of spectrum I can see why:

$(0,\infty) \subset \rho(\Delta_D)  \Rightarrow \sigma(\Delta_D) \subset \mathbb C \setminus (0,\infty)$

Hence, in order to deduce $(*)$ I should have used instead that: $\sigma(\Delta_D)=\mathbb R \setminus \rho(\Delta_D)$ but I don't get how this could be true here.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does remark 3.6 (xi) state?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which book are you studying?